# how to make sequence Images to Video using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Command:
execFFmpegBinary(new String[]{"-y", "-r", "11/2", "-i", inputImages, "-vcodec", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-preset", "ultrafast", outputpath});

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command so we can see the exact problem. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
#0:0 - may be incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

error self indicates that parameters like bitrate rate and height width are incorrect.
in most of the cases, height and width are wrong. check your width, height of `inputImages` images. Height or Width may be odd so FFmpeg throw this error

try below code

```
execFFmpegBinary(new String[]{"-y", "-r", "11/2", "-i", inputImages, "-filter_complex","scale=iw:-2","-vcodec", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-preset", "ultrafast", outputpath});
```

or

```
   execFFmpegBinary(new String[]{"-y", "-r", "11/2", "-i", inputImages, "-filter_complex","scale=-2:ih","-vcodec", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-preset", "ultrafast", outputpath});
```

Comment: Thanks brother,finally video created.

Comment: is my solution helps you?

Comment: mark it as Accpeted answer so other can find it as Perfect solution

Comment: my reputation is only one,dont have mark this answer.